# Service to Activity sticky communication

Tags: android, ipc, android-service

I have a service that downloads some data from internet and periodically sends progress to the indicator activity. In the end of processing service sends a result.

I have a question what is the best way to achieve persistence of the communication.

- Messenger or ResultReceiver, I need to parcel them into Intent and store list of listeners in the service. But on configuration change activity destroys, and it's hard to maintain this list.
- LocalBroadcastManager, I need to migrate from Messages to Intents, and also there is no sticky send in this class. So if I get result while my progress activity is in background result will be lost.
- BroadcastManager is good, but I don't need to broadcast my progress system wide, and security issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly do you want your application to behave when the download is done?

Comment: I'd like to have activity that resumes properly. For example show data in this activity (or start result activity)

Comment: So you want that your application can close, and once the download is done, it shows back up on the screen and displays the downloaded data?

Comment: Not completely close, it should run as long as OS has resources for this operation. But user should not be forced to watch progressbar, he could run email client or receive calls. But when user back to my activity he should see right progress

Comment: this is what you need : `http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger`

Comment: >> Messenger or ResultReceiver, I need to parcel them into Intent and store list of listeners in the service. But on configuration change activity destroys, and it's hard to maintain this list.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to give Otto (http://square.github.io/otto/) a try.

In your service, whenever you want to communicate with the activity, post a new event using a shared `Bus`. You should do that on main thread with a handler or main looper since you are probably using `IntentService`. The service may act as a producer as well. When your activity is recreated, current known value will be posted.

Your activity just needs to register with the `Bus` and subscribes to the right event. When it is paused, just unregister with the `Bus`.

Comment: I second Otto. It is a great library and sounds like it would be perfect for what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the best way to achieve that persistance is:

- After the service downloads, you should save your data in a database or a file.
- The service then sends broadcast to update.
- If the activity is "alive" all goes well and it goes to the database/file to get the updated content.
- If the activity was killed or something, you just have to make sure the data is in the database/file so that when you start/restart the activity you can get the latest content from database/file.
- While downloading keep a state and progress saved in the db/file the same way.

Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) Google I/O Session, it explains this really good.

Comment: File is not an answer, it's waste of SD cycles. And also there is a pain in case we like to have several processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use static variables inside your Application class (extends Application). Inside Service you set this variables. Inside Activity you read periodically this variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [massenger](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) to send download progress, because it is more secure and less expensive method then broadcast receiver.

Comment: How to maintain list of listeners, while Activity changes configuration, it's not trivial